# Capitalizing the letter in ArrayList using ListIterator

Tags: java, iterator, capitalization

I am trying to write a method to capitalize the first word of every element in an arraylist. So if the arraylist is:

> "mary had a little lamb"

It would need to change every element to:

> "Mary Had A Little Lamb"

This is the code, and this is the only way I can get it to compile. Every other way gives me an error that says that it can't convert an object to a String.

```
public static void capitalize(List<String> words)
{
    String str = "";
    ListIterator iter = words.listIterator();
    while (iter.hasNext())
    {
        str = iter.next() + "";
        str.toUpperCase();
        iter.set();
    }
}
```

Hope that was clear enough. Thanks

Comment: *Every other way* - like?

Comment: Do not forget to use a `ListIterator<String>` preferably

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since strings objects dont mutate this is not working:

```
str.toUpperCase();
```

the changes are getting done but are getting lost too

you have to do:

```
str = str.toUpperCase();
```

Comment: Wow thanks, didn't think I'd miss something that simple.

Comment: @KyleAK You may mark the answer as accepted now. :)